# Construct context-free grammars that generate for the languages L(G) = {01(110)^n 10 (11)^n : n >= 0}

Tags: finite-automata, context-free

I have given this question as home assignment. I tried a lot to solve it but couldn't found any solution. Please help 
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please add any attempts you have made towards solving the assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint, the grammar $S \to a S c \mid b$ generates the language $\{a^n b c^n : n \geq 0\}$. Can you you adapt this? Do you understand why it generates that language?